# Wordpress theme not uploading to Amazon EC2?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, amazon-ec2, varnish

I'm setting up a Wordpress blog on Amazon EC2 server with nginx and Varnish. I've followed [this tutorial](http://theartofcode.tv/installing-wordpress-on-ec2) step by step.

The blog is setup & working fine.

Now when I  try to upload a new theme through Wordpress, it starts uploading and by the time it reaches 70%(takes around 1 minute to reach 70%), the connection is abruptly disconnected with the `error code: ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED`

I'm guessing it is due to some connection timeout that's happening in nginx, varnish or somewhere else.

I'm new to this stuff. I did the following:

1. I changed the timeout in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`
   to `request_terminate_timeout = 500`
2. I changed the timeout in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to `fastcgi_read_timeout 500;`

But that didn't seem to work. I'm stuck. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same issue, here's the solution.
Solved it by adding the following settings:

php-fpm's php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 240
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
```

php-fpm's pool configuration

```
request_terminate_timeout = 240s
request_slowlog_timeout = 230s
slowlog = /var/log/php5-fpm.slow.log
```

nginx.conf

```
client_header_timeout 240;
client_body_timeout 240;
fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
client_max_body_size 32m;
```

All thanks to [this wonderful post](http://www.villescorner.com/2012/02/nginx-php-fpm-file-upload-battle.html)